# Getting geoserver to run faster

Tags: java, geoserver

I would like to know if there is anyway to speed up geoserver as I seem to be running out of options.

I have a base layer map that has 15 items on it that is need to make the map look decent.

I have also added the native JAI and the Native JAI ImageIO installed and its reading it although I had to reinstall everything on the 32 bit.

I am using geoserver 2.4.0 with tomcat 7 and java 7 on a windows machine.

It takes nearly 5min to load a section of the map and I need to try and increase the speed.

Answer (score 2):

First, have a look at this section of the documentation with some tips for production environments:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/index.html

Remember that projections are a great deal and that if the map info is not correctly defined or geoserver has to reproject everything, it'll take longer. You might also want to look into caching with GeoWebCache:

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/geowebcache/index.html

Bear in mind that if the layers you're trying to show are really heavy and you've not got them cached, geoserver will have to do all the renderization on the go which, depending on the amount of data, can take quite a while.

Last but not least, I also suggest you to have a look at any questions here or at the user mailing list which is quite active.